# UIPickerView with URL

Tags: xcode, url, web, uipickerview

I made a UIPickerView in xcode and I would like to add an "okay" or "go" button that will go to a specific website based on the selection on picker view. If any body know how to code this that would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Do you want help with the buttons or loading the web page? For the buttons, what I would do would be to either create a UIViewController subclass (the way Ive done it before) or a UIPickerView subclass (haven't tried this, but it sounds like a better idea) which has a picker in the view along with a UIBarbuttonItem above it that has your "OK" button.

Then, I would have that "OK" button hide the picker by setting it's frame offscreen (and probably removing it from it's superview) and then load the web page by getting the currently selected value on the picker.

---

When it comes to loading the web page, if you want it to stay in your app you would probably want to create a `UIWebView`, create an `NSURL` with the string of whatever your website address is.

Then you want to create an NSURLRequest from the url such as `NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]` and then call `[webView loadRequest:request];`

---

If you just want the link to be opened in safari, all you'd have to do is:
`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/"]];`

Comment: Each picker view choice would go to a different website

Comment: So you would have to have some sort of an array that stores the strings of each URL that the picker can take you to, then use the picker's currently selected row to determine which one to go to. (using the picker's `selectedRowInComponent:(NSInteger)component`).